# How to show Push notification as image

Tags: ios, ios6, base64, apple-push-notifications

i am working on one application in which server will send me image in base64 as a push notification  format as and from ios side i have to display this image with decode of base 64?I can do decoding and all but how i will display PNS as image
Is it possible to accept PNS as image(in base64)?

Code i am using as below,

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Push Notifications Methods
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
NSString *tokenStr = [deviceToken description];

// Separete Your device token with <,< and blanksapace
NSString *pushToken = [[[tokenStr
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"  withString:@""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">"  withString:@""]
                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "  withString:@""];

// Save the token to server
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.vijaywebsolutions.com/Development_FTP/webservice/webservices.php?deviceToken=%@",pushToken]; // Passing token to URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self]; // Support to perform URLrequest
if( theConnection )// checking connection successfull or not
{
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
    NSLog(@"device token is %@", pushToken);
}

}

 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
 didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) 
    {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Did receive a Remote Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Have a Notification :\n%@",userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The notification to the user will present the title and message text and then, if the user triggers the notification to open the app, your app will be passed the full notification data and you can display the image.